# Saving Asterisk CDR in 2 different databases

Tags: mysql, asterisk, asteriskami

I'm working on a PHP probject, but require some help in Asterisk PBX. For my project, I need to save Asterisk CDR on a remote database and also want to save the CDR in the existing database.

So my question is: Can we save Asterisk CDR in two different databases? One of them would be a MySQL database on same asterisk server and other database will be on a remote server. If yes, how can I achieve it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to correct its grammar and improve its phrasing a bit. I hope this way, it'll be easier for potential answerers to understand what you're asking. If you see room for improving your question yourself, feel free to edit it further. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put TWO sections in cdr_mysql.conf and it  will work like you want.

No need do complex things here

Also you can use for one cdr_mysql for other cdr_odbc(if other database is not mysql)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the second (extern) Databsase as Replication Slave and you can configure it so that only one table will replicated to the external DB. So its
not necessary to change anything in the Asterisk.

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/setting-up-replication/

Comment: I think this is not what he asked, becuase if first db stoped/failed replication will not work, while if asterisk have two connection - it will work ok(reability).

Comment: When the first DB stop/failed Asterisk also fails, but when it run or the connection is not always on the replication will start automaticly.

Comment: I think you just have not enought experience. DB can fail for multiple reason, most often when power loss. Asterisk work ok after restart, but database  require manual actions for reason of consistency.